# NullPointerException with MediaStore and ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception, cursor

Right after finally being able to list albums and the songs and all that other stuff, I've yet again have ANOTHER problem and that's this NullPointerException.

Now from what I've read and guessed, it's do with the ID of the albums song.

So i need help solving this little problem!

The code is a little messy at the moment so some stuff may have nothing to do with the code

```
    public class AlbumsList extends ListActivity{



public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 int count;
 Cursor cursor;
 ListView musiclist;
 int songAlbum;
 int position;
 AlbumSongs albums;
 String songTitle = "";
 String songPath = "";
long genreId;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.albums);


  String[] columns = { BaseColumns._ID,
            AlbumColumns.ALBUM };

        cursor =          getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            columns, null, null, null);

        String[] displayFields = new String[] { AlbumColumns.ALBUM };
        int[] displayViews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ListAdapter adapter = (new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, displayFields,
            displayViews));
          setListAdapter(adapter);


}
public AlbumsList(){

}
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          if(cursor.moveToPosition(position)){

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

         // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = this.getPlayList();


        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "songTitle", "songPath", "songId" }, new int[] {
                     android.R.id.text1});

              setListAdapter(adapter);

                ListView lv = getListView();

                // listening to single listitem click
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                        // getting listitem index
                        int songIndex = position;
                        // Starting new intent
                        Intent in = new Intent(AlbumsList.this,
                               MainActivity.class);
                        Log.d("TAG","onItemClick");
                        // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                        in.putExtra("songPath", songIndex);
                        startActivityForResult(in, 99);
                    // Closing PlayListView
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){

         String[] columns = { MediaColumns.DATA,
                  BaseColumns._ID,
                  MediaColumns.TITLE,
                  MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, };

              String where = BaseColumns._ID
                  + "=?";

              String whereVal[] = { cursor.getString(cursor
                  .getColumnIndex(AlbumColumns.ALBUM))};

              String orderBy = MediaColumns.TITLE;



              cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns,
                  where, whereVal, orderBy);

          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

        songTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.TITLE));
        songPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA));
        position = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID);
        genreId = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(position));

          HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();


         song.put("songTitle", songTitle);
         song.put("songPath", songPath);
         songsList.add(song);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

          }
          cursor.close();
        return songsList;

    }
   }
```

The problem seems to crop up when i start the app and the LogCat says it the NullPointer, and that the things causing it is the getPlayList() method!

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {



ListView musiclist;


private AlbumsList albumManager;


private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

private Albums albums;

private SongsManager songManager;
 Cursor cursor;


    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
              MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

                   //IT'S THIS PART!//          

        albumManager = new AlbumsList();
        songManager = new SongsManager();


                       // Getting all songs list
        songsList = albumManager.getPlayList();
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

                  //THIS PART //
```

The LogCat:

```
 04-02 17:04:51.761: E/SELinux(16136):   selinux_android_seapp_context_reload:seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{com.simplistic.simplisticmusicfree/com.simplistic.simplisticmusicfree.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
   04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
 04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
  04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
   04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
    04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
   04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native       Method)
 04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):   at com.simplistic.simplisticmusicfree.AlbumsList.getPlayList(AlbumsList.java:132)
 04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):   at com.simplistic.simplisticmusicfree.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:209)
 04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
 04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
 04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):   at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-02 17:04:52.452: E/AndroidRuntime(16136):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Which line is `AlbumsList.java:132`?

Comment: String whereVal[] = { cursor.getString(cursor
             .getColumnIndex(AlbumColumns.ALBUM))};

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cursor is not instantiated before you use it in `cursor.getString`. Remember that calling the constructor `AlbumList()` does not assure that `onCreate(...)` will also be called.